# ASP.net prevent gridview row click in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some issue with ASP.net Gridview that I hope people here can help me.

### Requirements

- Gridview whole row to be clickable to open another page
- In editing mode, can change table values through edititemtemplate textbox

### Problem

Textbox selection causes the entire row click event to fire and prevents user from changing the textbox text. User can edit table value without opening different page.

### ASP Page

```
<asp:GridView ID="remarksGV1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames="REM_ID"
            OnRowDataBound="remarksGV1_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="remarksGV1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            OnRowEditing="remarksGV1_RowEditing"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="remarksGV1_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowUpdating="remarksGV1_RowUpdating"
            AutoPostBack="false"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="thead-dark"
            CssClass="table table-striped thead-dark table-borderless table-hover border-0 hand"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="titleLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("REM_TITLE") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="titleTB" runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="REM_DESC" HeaderText="Remarks Description" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CREATE_DATE" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Date Created" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UPD_DATE" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Last Updated" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button Text="Edit" ID="EditBtn" CssClass="btn-action" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button Text="Update" ID="UpdateBtn" CssClass="btn-action" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                        <asp:Button Text="Cancel" ID="CancelBtn" CssClass="btn-action" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

### Code behind

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BindGrid called");

        int proj_code = Int32.Parse(ViewState["proj_cd"].ToString());

        ProjectRepository remarksRepository = new ProjectRepository();
        var remarks = remarksRepository.GetRemarks(proj_code, proj_task_code, proj_stask1_cd, proj_stask2_cd);
        remarksGV1.DataSource = remarks;
        remarksGV1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Launch.PageEvent(this, (LinkButton)sender, ViewState["proj_cd"].ToString());
    }

    protected void remarksGV1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (e.Row.RowType)
            {
                case DataControlRowType.Header:
                    //...
                    break;
                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(remarksGV1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //...throw
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox titleTB = (e.Row.FindControl("titleTB") as TextBox);

            int prj_cd = Int32.Parse(ViewState["proj_cd"].ToString());
            ProjectRepository repository = new ProjectRepository();
            var remarks = repository.GetRemarks(prj_cd, proj_task_code, proj_stask1_cd, proj_stask2_cd);
            Debug.WriteLine("Remarks Count: " + remarks.Count);
            TMS_PROJ_REMARK remark = remarks.First(x => x.REM_ID == Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "REM_ID")));

            if (titleTB != null)
            {
                titleTB.Text = remark.REM_TITLE;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void remarksGV1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = remarksGV1.SelectedIndex;
        long rem_id = (long)remarksGV1.DataKeys[row]["REM_ID"];
        Debug.WriteLine("REM ID: " + rem_id);

        Session["edit_remarks"] = true;
        Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pairs["rem_id"] = rem_id.ToString();
        pairs["proj_cd"] = ViewState["proj_cd"].ToString();
        Launch.ToPage(this, "Project_Remarks_In_2.aspx", pairs);
    }

    protected void btnAddRemarks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["new_remarks"] = true;
        Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pairs["proj_cd"] = ViewState["proj_cd"].ToString();

        string url = "Project_Remarks_In_1.aspx";

        Launch.ToPage(this, url, pairs);
    }

    private void SetTitle()
    {
        ProjectRepository repository = new ProjectRepository();
        TMS_PROJ_MASTER project = repository.GetProject(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["proj_cd"]));
        this.Title = "Remarks - " + project.PROJ_TITLE;
    }

    protected void remarksGV1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        remarksGV1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }

    protected void remarksGV1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do stuff
        ProjectRepository repository = new ProjectRepository();
        GridViewRow row = remarksGV1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        TextBox titleTB = (row.FindControl("titleTB") as TextBox);

        long rem_id = Convert.ToInt64(remarksGV1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        var db = new THPEntities();
        TMS_PROJ_REMARK remark = db.TMS_PROJ_REMARK
            .First(x => x.REM_ID == rem_id);
        remark.REM_TITLE = titleTB.Text;
        remark.UPD_DATE = DateTime.Now;
        db.SaveChanges();

        // Bind Grid
        remarksGV1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }

    protected void remarksGV1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        remarksGV1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest in this part of your code, do not add the full line click when you edit the line (I have add one -if- to check for the edit).

```
 switch (e.Row.RowType)
            {
                case DataControlRowType.Header:
                    //...
                    break;
                case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                    if((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) != DataControlRowState.Edit)
                           e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(remarksGV1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
                    break;
            }
```